# Javascript precision with math libraries

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get this calculation done in javascript using [Big.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)

```
r = (a * b)/ sqrt( ( a*sin(θ) )^2 + ( b*cos(θ) )^2 )
```

I've also tried math.js and have the same result.

You can see the discrepancies in Wolfram and Google calculations, as google is using javascript.
**[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2880*40%29%20%2F%20sqrt%28%2840%20cos%2890%29%29%5E2%2B%2880%20sin%2890%29%29%5E2%29)** [=40] vs **[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=(80*40)%20%2F%20sqrt((40%20cos(90))%5E2%2B(80%20sin(90))%5E2)&gws_rd=ssl)** [=43.4008369271]

I've done this jsfiddle where you can see it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/herkulano/k1h5d4zk/

**How do you solve it?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Still 40.00000005 is much closer than 43.4008369271 :)

Comment: My question is: **How to solve it?**

Comment: See my answer, simply convert the degree value to radians and plug it in and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that javascript by default uses radians and in your example, Wolfram is defaulting to degrees. You can convert degrees to radians with a function like this.

```
function degToRad(deg){
return deg*(Math.PI/180)
}
```